# Is it possible to exclude sources from scalastyle with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalastyle

I am using scalastyle with sbt and I would like to exclude some generated sources (e.g. generated by Slick schema generator). Is there any setting for that ?

Comment: For now I modified the code generator by adding `// scalastyle:off` to the beginning of the generated code and `// scalastyle:off` to then end of it. It works but still, it will be good if it can be configured  without modifying the code itself.

Comment: second scalastyle:off is actually scalastyle:on

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508749/excluding-folder-from-scalastyle-sbt-plugin/41510174