# excluding folder from scalastyle sbt plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, scalastyle

All the other questions I've found on this topic are quite old.

I am building a scala project with `sbt` and the `scala-style` plugin but I can't find a way to exclude a specific folder where I have some generated code.

Is there a way to force the plugin to not check that particular folder?

Right now I am editing the files manually and adding:

`// scalastyle:off`

on the top of the file, but this is quite annoying.

In the official website http://www.scalastyle.org/sbt.html I couldn't find any documentation, although it seems that it is actually possible to exclude paths/files from it.

https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle/blob/e19b54eacb6502b47b1f84d7b2a6b5d33f3993bc/src/main/scala/org/scalastyle/Main.scala#L51

so it seems that we can actually pass:

```
println(" -x, --excludedFiles STRING      regular expressions to exclude file paths (delimited by semicolons)")
```

In my `build.sbt` I call:

```
lazy val compileScalastyle = taskKey[Unit]("compileScalastyle")
compileScalastyle := org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin.scalastyle.in(Compile).toTask("").value
(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn compileScalastyle
```

Is there a way to achieve that with the `sbt plugin`?

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle-sbt-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalastyle/sbt/Plugin.scala#L112) you should probably override `scalastyleSources in Compile`. Default is the folder `src/main/scala`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get all files/directories under "src/main/scala" and filter out your directory:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    (scalastyleSources in Compile) := {
      // all .scala files in "src/main/scala"
      val scalaSourceFiles = ((scalaSource in Compile).value ** "*.scala").get    
      val fSep = java.io.File.separator // "/" or "\"
      val dirNameToExclude = "com" + fSep + "folder_to_exclude" // "com/folder_to_exclude"
      scalaSourceFiles.filterNot(_.getAbsolutePath.contains(dirNameToExclude))
    }
  )
```

**EDIT**:
I've added a more "generic" solution where it checks the path of each file to exclude...

Comment: weird, I tried to print the sources inside there but it only prints the initial name of a folder under `src/`

I print it as:
`      scalaSourceFiles.foreach((f: File) => println("name: " + f.getName))`

and it only prints `com` for folder `com.mystuff`

Comment: This only goes one level deep (`listFiles()` method on `java.io.File`). If you want all files under src there are sbt's helpers like `**` method that will give you **all** files under a folder. See [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Paths.html#Selecting+descendants). See how your folder structure looks like and exclude wanted files...

Comment: thanks! could you help me excluding a folder under `scala/folder1/folder_to_exclude` ?
I'm new in scala

Comment: I tried: 
`scalastyleSources in Compile -= baseDirectory.value / "src" / "scala" / "com" / "folder_to_exclude"` but it didn't work :(

Comment: sweet, that solved my problem! I couldn't figure out how to write this line:
`val scalaSourceFiles = ((scalaSource in Compile).value ** "*.scala").get`